# Why does data get corrupted while reading from internal flash memory of STM32 Blue-Pill

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, flash-memory

I am writing and reading from internal flash memory of STM32 Blue Pill. Writing is successfully done. but while reading data, only specific bytes of data get corrupted.

Code block for reading data from flash memory:

```c
uint8_t *Read_Buffer;
uint16_t Read_Size = 8192;
uint32_t Internal_Flash_Address = 0x0800C000;
Read_Buffer = (uint8_t *) malloc(Read_Size * sizeof(uint8_t));

for(uint16_t j=0; j<Read_Size; j++){
    Read_Buffer[j] = *(__IO uint8_t *)Internal_Flash_Address;
    Internal_Flash_Address++;
}
while(CDC_Transmit_FS(Read_Buffer, Read_Size) != USBD_OK){};
free(Read_Buffer);
```

Data I write:
[image]

Data read back, memory locations marked with yellow are wrongly received data:
[image]

Although, the data is written accurately in the memory which I can confirm by checking the memory in STMCubeProgrammer:
[image]
I doubt this is data corruption because when reading 8KB of flash only 156-Bytes are corrupted, and every time this exact memory locations are causing problem while reading back, but memory still holds proper data as per STM32CubeProgrammer.

What can be other reasons for such data corruption while reading back data using pointers pointing at memory locations in the memory?

Comment: This snippet alone is absolutely insufficient to tell anything about the problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That is the only section that I use to read data and I transmit it over USB channel, I have added the USB line as well, please check.

Comment: Possibly your write code is not properly erasing and writing a complete block.

Comment: @stark I am doing page erase of 1024Bytes, if that was the case shouldn't it affect the whole 1024-Bytes to be written? but I can see correct data after this wrongly received bytes

Comment: Does your CPU have cache?

Comment: @stark, and data is actually written correctly which iIcan see in STMCubeProgrammer, so the problem seems to be in the reading part

Comment: @stark, The STM32 Blue-Pill? No, it doesn't have any cache memory

Comment: I see you are using `malloc`, which is unusual for bare-metal environment. Are you using an RTOS? If not, how your `malloc` is implemented?

Comment: @EugeneSh. In my code block I have assigned Read_Size as 8192-Bytes for simplicity, but in project implementation the Read_Size is received from user and then that much memory is allocated using malloc. No I am not using RTOS

Comment: @EugeneSh., but thanks, I am not sure as of why malloc is not implemented in bare-metal as I am a beginner, I'll add a new question. If you may please answer it in brief there

Comment: I also do not see that you are checking `malloc`return result. Try reading into a statically allocated buffer instead, and see what happens.

Comment: @EugeneSh., Sorry I don't understand what you mean by malloc implementation? In my code, only the malloc line is doing the work, nothing else related malloc() is there other than free()

Comment: @EugeneSh., I can't statically allocate memory for Read_Size, because Read_Size is user input, that is why I have to do run-time memory allocation

Comment: Allocate the maximum allowed size. And we are talking about experiment here

Comment: @EugeneSh., static allocation works, but that is not useful for my use case, where I need to take input during runtime, hope you understand, thanks for your input

Comment: It means that your dynamic allocation doesn't work. Check what your `malloc` is returning, likely `NULL`. In bare-metal environment you are usually required to provide your own `malloc` implementation, or do certain setup work to make the existing one to work. Can't help you here with details, you will have to do some research.

Comment: Thanks! Okay I'll look into implementing my own ```malloc()```, thank you for your time.

Comment: Why do you need to allocate a buffer for reading out? You could either use a fixed size small buffer, e.g. 512Bytes, and read to buffer and give out from that buffer, until the requested data size has been read out e.g ReadSize/512. Or, you could even try to directly give it out from internal flash, without a buffer inbetween.

Comment: @Diracx you do not need to implement your own malloc, you simply need to ensure that you have provided whatever support for it your particular toolchain's library requires.  That may only require defining the heap size, or for Newlib for example defining sbrk. Your argument for requiring dynamic rather than static allocation is specious since you do not check the success of the allocation.  If you have insufficient heap, it still won't work, you are simply allowing the user to crash your code by entering a size that cannot be satisfied.

Comment: Since code is ex cuted from flash, there is clearly no issue with reading flash.  You are reading that data into _RAM_, then transferring it over _USB_, then presenting that in a PC.  The error might occur anywhere in that chain.  Use a debugger to inspect both the flash and the RAM copy at the point before you transfer it to determine which side of that divide the error has occured

Comment: The first question to ask is: how big is the heap? Check your linker script. If it's less than 8kb then that's the problem.